# i just install ubuntu 12.10 and my wirless adapter isn't working

Tags: drivers

`sudo lshw -C network -numeric`:

```
*-network               
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14E4:4311]
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation [14E4]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0b:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=b43-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:efdfc000-efdfffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX [14E4:170C]
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation [14E4]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth1
       version: 02
       serial: 00:19:b9:78:01:ad
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=b44 driverversion=2.0 duplex=full ip=192.168.1.6 latency=64 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:17 memory:ef9fe000-ef9fffff
```

Answer (score 2):

With a temporary wired ethernet connection, open the terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
sudo modprobe -r b43 && sudo modprobe b43
```

Detach the ethernet and your wireless should now be working.